# Can't connect Macbook Pro5,5 Ethernet Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, ethernet, macbook

I have installed single-boot Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image) in my Macbook Pro 13' mid 2009 (5.5) but I don't have Ethernet connection when connecting directly to the router (WIFI does not work as there are no drivers and I need Ethernet to install them). I have checked other posts but none of them worked for my case.

```
$lspci | grep Ethernet
Ethernet Controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Ethernet (rev b1)

$lshw -C network
*-network
    description: Ethernet interfaces
    product: MCP79 Ethernet
    vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
    physical id: a
    bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
    logical name: enp0s10
    version: b1
    serial: 00:26:bb:50:68:00
    capacity: 1Gbit/s
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 66 Mhz
    capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII
    resources: irq:27 memory:d3486000-d3486fff ioport:21e0(size=8)

$lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
[8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. Airport Extreme [106b:008d] 
Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

$ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s10: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:26:bb:50:68:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enxa0cec8110a68: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether a0:ce:c8:11:0a:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s10: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc 
pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:26:bb:50:68:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enxa0cec8110a68: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc 
pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:ce:c8:11:0a:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::50a2:7f33:f321:9404/64 scope link
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to add the output of `ip link show`?

Comment: @vidarlo I have added it

Comment: Looks like it finds two Ethernet cards. What makes you believe Ethernet is not working?

Comment: It says it can't connect to it

Comment: What is it that says so?

Comment: In both cards tries to get connection but can't, I have attached a picture

Comment: What's the output of `ip a` when Network Manager says connected for the USB card?

Comment: Sorry to ask but how do I check the Network Manager?

Comment: In the picture you posted it shows that the USB NIC is connected. Simply run `ip a` in a terminal when it shows the same as in the screenshot you posted :)

Comment: I have edited @vidarlo